# LDFLAGS usage in autotools with libtool

Tags: autotools, libtool, ldflags

Depending on the OS, I define a special `LDFLAGS` in my configure.ac:

```
AC_CANONICAL_HOST
if test "$host_os" = cygwin
then
    LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -Wl,-no-undefined"
    export LDFLAGS
fi
AC_SUBST([LDFLAGS])
```

The package uses `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL` and when `LDFLAGS` is passed to libtool, the `-Wl` prefix remains, and the linker doesn't understand the option. If I remove this prefix, the `AC_PROG_CXX` macro fails, because GCC chokes on `-no-undefined` by itself. What am I doing wrong?

`LDFLAGS` is not mentioned the `Makefile.am`, but I have made sure that it is honored in the libtool command by running `make -n`.

I'm using autoconf 2.69, automake 1.14, gmake 4.0 and gcc 4.8.2 under Cygwin 1.7.28(0.271/5/3)

Edit: I have a few dozen `Makefile.am`s, more than half of which are from external libraries -- I'd much prefer to control these flags from a central location.

Comment: That should probably be `-Wl,--no-undefined` (note 2 `-`s) not `-Wl,-no-undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ordered not to modify dozens of Makefiles, I have ended up using `LDFLAGS`. The trick was to set it after the `AC_PROG_CXX` macro:

```
AC_PROG_CXX
if test "$host_os" = cygwin
then
    LDFLAGS="-no-undefined $LDFLAGS"
fi
AC_SUBST([LDFLAGS])
```

This way, the macro that tests for a C++ compiler succeeds because LDFLAGS is pristine; but the actual codebase uses the extra flag.

By putting the `$LDFLAGS` substitution at the end, any user options from the environment take precedence at configure time; and overriding at make time with `make LDFLAGS=...` is still possible.

Comment: Technically, these are hacks, since the dependencies and orderings for these variables aren't documented. In practice, the autotools are about getting the job done. This is elegant, and good to know!

Answer (score 4):

Libtool has a `-no-undefined` option.

GNU ld has a `--no-undefined` option.

You should let libtool know about it from inside the *Makefile.am*, and let it take care of forwarding to the linker:

**configure.ac**

```
AC_CANONICAL_HOST
if test "$host_os" = cygwin
then
    EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-no-undefined"
fi
AC_SUBST([EXTRA_LDFLAGS])
```

**Makefile.am**

```
AM_LDFLAGS = $(EXTRA_LDFLAGS) ...
```

As a general rule, you should not mess around with CPPFLAGS, LDFLAGS, etc from configure.ac, since the user might need to change them while invoking "make".

Comment: This is spot on - leave the environment variables that are picked up by `configure` alone.

Comment: I have a few dozen `Makefile.am`s which mach the `^lib` regex (i.e. define `libXXX` variables). I'd still prefer to influence all of these makefiles from a central location if possible, than changing every single `Makefile.am`. Will something like `AC_SUBST([AM_LDFLAGS], "--no-undefined") work? None of those `Makefile.am`s explicitly set `AM_LDFLAGS`...