# What do link flags mean for static library?

Tags: c++, c, linker, static-libraries, automake

"ar" -- is just tool to create archives.

And all static libraries of form "lib*.a" are in fact just archived compiled objects + additional file with symbol table, added there by "ranlib".
No linking is performing during creation of such library.

So why do most of projects use `***_LDFLAGS` `***_LIBADD` in their `Makefile.am` during creation of such ("lib*.a" static library) archives?

Does automake ignore those flags (in case when they relate to any "lib*.a" static library), or does it in fact link something there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So why do most of projects use `***_LDFLAGS` `***_LIBADD` in their Makefile.am during creation of such ("lib*.a" static library) archives?

The GNU Build System is capable of creating dynamic and static libs (or both) determined at `configure` time using the `--enable-shared` and `--enable-static` flags.  As you guessed, `_LDFLAGS` and `_LIBADD` are more oriented to dynamic shared objects or program linkage than to the static linker.  The static linker of `libtool` is essentially another link pass that invokes `ar` to create the archive (omitting all the flags).  For example:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES=libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES=$(SRCS)
libfoo_la_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-t
```

when both shared and static libs are generated outputs something like:

```
libtool: link: gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/foo.o    -g -O2 -Wl,-t   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libfoo.so.0 -o .libs/libfoo.so.0.0.0
...
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libfoo.so.0" && ln -s "libfoo.so.0.0.0" "libfoo.so.0")
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libfoo.so" && ln -s "libfoo.so.0.0.0" "libfoo.so")
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libfoo.a  foo.o
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libfoo.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libfoo.la" && ln -s "../libfoo.la" "libfoo.la" )
```

`automake` does ignore `_LDFLAGS`; however the script that performs the linking (`libtool`) does not.  It looks for flags that affect linking there also.  For example:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES=libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES=$(SRCS)
libfoo_la_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-t -static
```

will *only* generate a static lib, even if `configure --disable-static` was run to generate the Makefile.

`libtool` is just a wrapper script over the native compiler/linker tools for portability.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question `Does automake ignore them` is: **NO**

That is completely true: ""ar" -- is just tool to create archives."

But, Automake does not ignore `***_LDFLAGS` `***_LIBADD` in their `Makefile.am` at all, otherwise what is point of having such flag if they are not making any sense for the build system!

From documentation (link give below):

- The ‘`library_LIBADD`’ variable should be used to list extra *libtool* objects (**.lo files**) or *libtool* libraries (**.la**) to add to library.
- The ‘`library_LDFLAGS`’ variable is the place to list additional *libtool* linking flags, such as `-version-info`, `-static`, and a lot more.

For more details, you should go through this Libtool Documentation for more clarity in these flags.

- [8.3.7 _LIBADD, _LDFLAGS, and _LIBTOOLFLAGS](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Libtool-Flags.html)
- [Libtool Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#A-Shared-Library)

**EDIT**:
As your question is still generic, let me put it in two different scenario...

1. **Static Lib is stand-alone**:

   - In this scenario `***_LIBADD` could be not much useful, as mentioned in documentation: "**the `library_LIBADD` variable should be used to list extra libtool objects (`.lo` files) or libtool libraries (`.la`) to add to** *library*"
   - Which means, if your static lib does not have dependency then this flag is no of use in it's `Makefile.am`.
2. **Static Lib is Dependent (not stand-alone)**

   - From above quote from documentation, it is now clear that, `***_LIBADD` flag is used to mentioned libs names which are required to build your current *library*.
   - So this flag would be necessary in such requirement.

And about `***_LDFLAGS`, as mentioned in documentation, **The `library_LDFLAGS` variable is the place to list additional libtool linking flags** for that library.

- If your lib does not require such flags, then this can be ignored too. It is all about how you want your final result.

Few more additional links for your reference:

- [LDFLAGS usage in autotools with libtool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840315/ldflags-usage-in-autotools-with-libtool)
- [What is the difference between LDADD and LIBADD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685981/what-is-the-difference-between-ldadd-and-libadd)

I hope this EDIT suffices what you're looking for.

PS: If you would read my answer carefully and went through documentation, you could have get the same data. Njoy. :)